Simplifications to a Large (Dottie) Integral
While working on a problem, I encountered this integral.
$$
\alpha \in \left(-\frac{3\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2}\right),\ \ \ \mathfrak{D}_{\alpha }=\pi+\frac{1}{\pi}\int _0^{\infty }\left(1-\cosh \left(z\right)\right)\left(\frac{\frac{9\pi ^2}{4}+\frac{3\pi }{2}\alpha -z\sinh \left(z\right)+z^2}{\left(\sinh \left(z\right)-z\right)^2+\left(\frac{3\pi }{2}+\alpha \right)^2}-\frac{\frac{\pi ^2}{4}+z^2-z\sinh \left(z\right)-\frac{\pi }{2}\alpha }{\left(\alpha -\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2+\left(z-\sinh \left(z\right)\right)^2}\right)\mathrm{d}z
$$
Derriving inspiration from this paper (NOTE: THIS LINK DOWNLOADS A PDF!!) I also found that:
$$
\alpha \in \left(-\frac{\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2}\right), \ \ \ \mathfrak{D}_{\alpha }=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _0^{\infty }\ln \left(\frac{\left(t+\sinh \left(t\right)\right)^2+\left(\alpha +\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2}{\left(t-\sinh \left(t\right)\right)^2+\left(\alpha -\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t
$$
Are there any simplifications possible to express the first integral more concisely?
(If you are curious, $\mathfrak{D}_{\alpha }=\cos \left(\cos \left(\cdots \left(\cos \left(x\right)-\alpha \right)\cdots -\alpha \right)-\alpha \right)-\alpha $. Which is the solution to $\cos \left(x\right)-x=\alpha $).

This is a very nice problem ! $(+1)$
